# FragmentActivity always on screen

Tags: wear-os, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragmentActivity (public class WearRunActivity extends FragmentActivity) that I want to be always on on the screen.

I can't setAmbientEnabled(); because it is not an wearableActivity....

How can i keep my app on

Comment: Why did my question was voted down? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag to keep your activity on:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

However, be very careful and mindful of the user's battery consumption. You can clear this flag as soon as you don't need your activity to stay on by calling

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: I've found that workaround, but there is no real way to let the screen go on ambient mode instead of being completely on without WearableActivity?

Comment: No, you won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider`
callback instead.

It is the new preferred method and it still gives you all stuff WearableActivity gave you but also lets you use `Activity` (or any sub classes... FragementActivity, etc.).

[Official docs call out the details (and example code)](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AmbientMode.AmbientCallbackProvider {

    /*
     * Declare an ambient mode controller, which will be used by
     * the activity to determine if the current mode is ambient.
     */
    private AmbientMode.AmbientController mAmbientController;
    …
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
        mAmbientController = AmbientMode.attachAmbientSupport(this);
    }
    ...

    …
    @Override
    public AmbientMode.AmbientCallback getAmbientCallback() {
        return new MyAmbientCallback();
    }
    …

private class MyAmbientCallback extends AmbientMode.AmbientCallback {
    @Override
    public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
             // Handle entering ambient mode
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitAmbient() {
      // Handle exiting ambient mode
     }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbient() {
      // Update the content
    }
}
```